# ERROR al abrir apk generada por android studio [Resuelto]

Tags: android, android-studio, archivo, apk

al darle RUN desde android studio, y testear la aplicación, en mi celular funciona correctamente, pero cuando genero la aplicación e intento instalarla me salta un error(adjunto imagen), alguién sabe cuál puede ser el problema? Generé tanto por debug, como en release, ambas versiones, utilicé "gradle assemble", aplicación firmada, sin firmar, aún no logro instalar un apk, siempre me sale ese mensaje de error. gracias...

Al final tuve que firmar la aplicación, generar con las 2 versiones que te aparecen, y subir el apk a google drive, luego descargaba el apk y listo...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo buildeas el apk?

Comment: La solución va en la zona de respuestas y no en la pregunta, por favor edita y corrige